# How set language in Json of google map api?

Tags: android, google-maps

I get json of google map as:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=34.431741,135.392299&destination=34.631741,135.992299&sensor=false
```

Result of google return:

```
 "legs" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "79,8 km",
                  "value" : 79756
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "1 giờ 20 phút",
                  "value" : 4818
               },
               "end_address" : "Meihan National Hwy, Nara 632-0102, Nhật Bản",
               "end_location" : {
                  "lat" : 34.630910,
                  "lng" : 135.992630
               },
               "start_address" : "Nhật Bản ŌsakaKishiwadaNagaregicho, ３９６−３",
               "start_location" : {
                  "lat" : 34.431530,
                  "lng" : 135.392670
               },
....
...
```

How can I get the JSON data in Japanese language?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add language parameter..

```
..&language=ja
```

Your sample call [here](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=34.431741,135.392299&destination=34.631741,135.992299&sensor=false&language=ja), documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Localization).